# PDF.js error : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

I am using PDF.js to display a pDF (cause my chromium version is embedded and cannot open pdf natively).

i've already builded again this library using node-gyp and followed all the insctructions found [on this github page](https://github.com/benjamind/delarre.docpad/blob/master/src/documents/posts/installing-node-canvas-for-windows.html.md) (and yeah i've already moved the DLLs like it's said)

I still having this error :

```
viewer.js:5667 renderView: "Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
\\?\C:\pathtomyproject\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node"
```

If someone wanna reproduce the issue :
OS : Windows 10 uptodate
nodejs version 12.7
PDF.js ECMA5 compatible
And using PDF.js example page modified to get a custom get parameter (for the path of the PDF that musts be dynamic)

modifs on line 4892 :

```js
function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
  let sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
      sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
      sParameterName,
      i;
  for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
    sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

    if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
      console.log(atob(sParameterName[1]))
      return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : atob(sParameterName[1]);
    }
  }
}

var OptionKind = {
  VIEWER: 0x02,
  API: 0x04,
  WORKER: 0x08,
  PREFERENCE: 0x80
};
exports.OptionKind = OptionKind;
var defaultOptions = {
  cursorToolOnLoad: {
    value: 0,
    kind: OptionKind.VIEWER + OptionKind.PREFERENCE
  },
  defaultUrl: {
    value: getUrlParameter("url"),
    kind: OptionKind.VIEWER
  },
```

Thanks

Comment: Try nodejs version 10.  The "canvas" package sometimes has trouble building on later nodejs version.

Comment: i must haven't be clear enough, i cannot change my nodejs version, it's the embedded version in adobe CEP10